# Copy specific cells from one spreadsheet to another in the same workbook using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google form that is capturing client data to a Google spreadsheet workbook with 2 tabs; sheet1 = Traffic and sheet2 = ComMan. I am trying to move the data captured in my variable "spot1" from the Traffic Tab to the ComMan tab and can't figure out how to do it. I know everything works up to the line **sheet.getRange(spot1).copyTo(targetRange);**. I'm hoping someone can help. Thanks for your time.

Here's my code:

```
function onEdit() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r = sheet.getActiveCell();
var rowIndex = r.getRow();

var sheet1 = "Traffic"; //the active spreadsheet
var sheet2 = "ComMan"; //the ComMan Tab
var status1Col = 19;//status1Col if "No"
var status1Value = "ComMan";//if status1Col = "No", select "ComMan" in the status1Value to send to the ComMan tab

var clientInfo = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, 5);//cols A:E contain client info
var status1Range = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 11, 1, 5);//cols K:O contain spot 1 info
var comDelValue = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 60, 1, 1);//col BG contains spot 1 delivery method

var spot1 = [[clientInfo.getValues()],[spot1Info.getValues()],[comDelInfo.getValues]]; //an array to capture all the spot 1 data in one shot

//the statement below will copy the date in spot1 variable and send it to the ComMan tab
if (sheet.getName() == sheet1 && range.getColumn() == status1Col && 
range.getValue() == status1Value){
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet2);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() +1, 1);
sheet.getRange(spot1).copyTo(targetRange);
}
}
```

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: This is a debugging problem. Print out the intermediate variable values at points of your own choosing to see which values are not as you expect. Work them out on paper first if necessary.

Comment: What's the error? What's the expected behavior? What's the observed behavior? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask help us help you.

Comment: spot1Info is undefined,comDelInfo is also undefined

Comment: `[[clientInfo.getValues()],[spot1Info.getValues()],[comDelInfo.getValues]];` It's a 2d array of 2d arrays.  It's not something you can use anywhere in a spreadsheet. AFAIK. And certainly not in this case: `sheet.getRange(spot1).copyTo(targetRange)` You need to read the documentation carefully and do some debugging on your own.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you want to be able to do something like the following.  So hopefully this will help you out.

```
function copyDisconnectedRangesToAnotherSheet(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet22');
  var rowIndex=2
  var vA = sh.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, 5).getValues()[0];//cols A:E contain client info
  var vB = sh.getRange(rowIndex, 11, 1, 5).getValues()[0];//cols K:O contain spot 1 info
  var vC = sh.getRange(rowIndex, 60, 1, 1).getValues()[0];//col BG contains spot 1 delivery method
  var vD=vA.concat(vB.concat(vC));
  var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,vD.length);
  rg.setValues([vD]);
  rg.copyTo(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet21').getRange(1,1));//copied to A1
  rg.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: thank you! I am immensely grateful for your help. I appreciate your willingness to see what I was trying to accomplish and provide a solution. I was able to take what you provided and apply it to my code. It worked, as I'm sure you knew. I struggled with this problem for many days and it kept me awake at night. Again, I am immensely grateful for your help! All my best thoughts go to you today!